# Codeigniter active records with join 4 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

guys i have 4 table `uhd_voucher_menu`, `uhd_menu`, `uhd_voucher_variant_menu`, `uhd_variant_menu`

which `uhd_voucher_menu` and `uhd_menu` is connected by `menu_id`, than `uhd_voucher_variant_menu` and `uhd_voucher_menu` is connected by `voucher_menu_id` and the last,  `uhd_variant_menu` and `voucher_variant_menu` is connected by `variant_menu_id`

this is my code how i get the data :

```
        $this->db->select("uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_id,uhd_menu.menu_name,uhd_voucher_menu.qty,uhd_variant_menu.variant_name,uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_menu_id");
        $this->db->from("uhd_voucher_menu");
        $this->db->join("uhd_menu","uhd_menu.menu_id = uhd_voucher_menu.menu_id");
        $this->db->join("uhd_voucher_variant_menu","uhd_voucher_variant_menu.voucher_menu_id = uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_menu_id","left");
        $this->db->join("uhd_variant_menu","uhd_variant_menu.variant_menu_id = uhd_voucher_variant_menu.variant_menu_id","left");
        $this->db->where("voucher_id",$data["voucher"]["voucher_id"]);
        $this->db->where("uhd_menu.restaurant_id",$restaurant_id);
        $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

from that active recored will be return to this data :

```
[0]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(5) "Spicy"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
[1]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(6) "Medium"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
[2]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(4) "Sour"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
[3]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(6) "Medium"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
[4]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(14) "Red Crown Crab"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  NULL
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
[5]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(8) "Omellete"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  NULL
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

as you see the `golden_salmon` with same `voucher_menu_id` is return twice

i want if the `voucher_menu_id` is same, so from this data :

```
[0]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(5) "Spicy"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
[1]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  string(6) "Medium"
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

i want that data return to become this :

```
[0]=>
array(5) {
  ["voucher_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["menu_name"]=>
  string(13) "Golden Salmon"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["variant_name"]=>
  array(2){
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Spicy"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Medium"
  }
  ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

same as the other `golden_salmon` with same `voucher_menu_id` `4`

i want the `variant_name` is become array so the if data with same `voucher_menu_id` will not call twice

guys can you help me how to execute the data as i want?
thank you (:

Answer (score -1):

You have to use group by, I slightly modified you query:

```
 $this->db->select("uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_id,uhd_menu.menu_name,uhd_voucher_menu.qty,GROUP_CONCAT(uhd_variant_menu.variant_name SEPARATOR ',') AS variants,uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_menu_id");
    $this->db->from("uhd_voucher_menu");
    $this->db->join("uhd_menu","uhd_menu.menu_id = uhd_voucher_menu.menu_id");
    $this->db->join("uhd_voucher_variant_menu","uhd_voucher_variant_menu.voucher_menu_id = uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_menu_id","left");
    $this->db->join("uhd_variant_menu","uhd_variant_menu.variant_menu_id = uhd_voucher_variant_menu.variant_menu_id","left");
    $this->db->where("voucher_id",$data["voucher"]["voucher_id"]);
    $this->db->where("uhd_menu.restaurant_id",$restaurant_id);
$this->db->group_by("uhd_voucher_menu.voucher_id");
    $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

we can convert the comma seperated values to array after query output.

Try and post the result...

Comment: its only return 1 data

Comment: Post your generated query using,
echo $this->db->last_query();